# How to decode special characters in queryParams in Angular 6?

Tags: angular

I need to preprocess queryParams and convert them to proper links:
For example user enters the following link:

```
http://myapp.com/?query=string&amp;filter=1&amp;sort=desc
```

I need to convert back all special characters:

```
http://myapp.com/?query=string&filter=1&sort=desc
```

Otherwise queryParams object has the following result:

```
{
  amp;query: "string"
  amp;filter: 1,
  amp;sort: "desc",
}
```

Comment: I can see no special characters in that. & is standard parameter separator.

Comment: Its stackoverflow decoded them :) See now

Comment: & should not be encoded at all.

Comment: It depends where and how you are gonna use it https://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html#escaping. String is irrelevant to the question. I was thinking to use history.replaceState() to replace occurrences. But, perhaps there is better solution.

Comment: No it should not be encoded. Moreover, if it is encoded, then it should be URL encoded (with %). &code; is HTLM escaping character. So again - it should not be encoded that way. 

Plain & is a query var n ame separtor and any & will be threated like that - as separator. In general as you suggest you want 3 vars ther (query, filter,sort) then its is MALFORMED QUERY STRING.

Comment: Once again the link above is correct, it's UTF 8 encoded (ref to the link provided above) . It's automatically generated sitemap for the app. The problems are: 1 if I am not encoding & characters xml sitemaps is invalid. 2. By encoding & characters in query string, angular app doesn't read them properly, separating by & only.

Comment: And once again it is invalid. You can argue with standards, or just follow them. It seems you took the first option.

Comment: `?query=string&filter=1&sort=desc` would be valid query string understood correctly and parsed correctly by any browser/framework you could imagine. And for the last time - `&code;` is used in HTML to encode special characters, not in URIs. Due to malformation you got results like presented above.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a full example
https://stackblitz.com/edit/hello-angular-6-decode-special

**Angular 6 Example**

```
  link = 'http://myapp.com/?query=string&amp;filter=1&amp;sort=desc';
  newLink = '';

  constructor() {
    // I can't use a script tag in this example
    this.newLink = this.decodeEntities(this.link);
  }

  decodeEntities(str) {
    // this prevents any overhead from creating the object each time
    const element = document.createElement('div');
    if(str && typeof str === 'string') {
        // strip script/html tags
        str = str.replace(/<script[^>]*>([\S\s]*?)<\/script>/gmi, '');
        str = str.replace(/<\/?\w(?:[^"'>]|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')*>/gmi, '');
        element.innerHTML = str;
        str = element.textContent;
        element.textContent = '';
      }
      return str;
  }
```

**Core Javascript Example**

```
var decodeEntities = (function() {
  // this prevents any overhead from creating the object each time
  var element = document.createElement('div');

  function decodeHTMLEntities (str) {
    if(str && typeof str === 'string') {
      // strip script/html tags
      str = str.replace(/<script[^>]*>([\S\s]*?)<\/script>/gmi, '');
      str = str.replace(/<\/?\w(?:[^"'>]|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')*>/gmi, '');
      element.innerHTML = str;
      str = element.textContent;
      element.textContent = '';
    }

    return str;
  }

  return decodeHTMLEntities;
})();


// I can't use a script tag in this example
var text = decodeEntities('http://myapp.com/?query=string&amp;filter=1&amp;sort=desc');

document.write(text);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But the requirement is different. I reckon if you read my last comment under the post, you will understand what I need. Generally speaking I need to alter query separate rendering function.